# Unregistering M3 models

Tags: memory, rascal

What is the current preferred way of unregistering M3 models from the Registry?

In my project I'm using Rascal to analyse ~100 large java programs and my JVM is slowly running out of memory. I found the unregisterProject method in older versions of the Registry and tried using this code but I don't think it's working correctly.

```
public void unregisterProject(loc project, M3 model) {
    rel[str scheme, loc name, loc src] perScheme 
      = {<name.scheme, name, src> | <name, src> <- model.declarations};

    for (str scheme <- perScheme<scheme>) {
           unregisterLocations(scheme, project.authority);
    }
}
```

My current workaround is to throw a large amount of memory at the problem.

Comment: Hi Felix; do you think there is a bug? if so, what do you observe and when? if so, maybe you could submit an issue here with your findings: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/ It would be much appreciated.

Comment: that old code indeed looks buggy. I'll try and write a better version.

Comment: Well my code should not have any side effects as all the data stored should be cleaned up by the garbage collection. Is there an easier way to see the memory usage (other than looking at Eclipse's heap status)? I extracted a few heap dumps using Eclipse's memory analyzer but I couldn't find an obvious culprit.

Comment: A heapdump would also be my next suggestion; but model registration is a "memory leak" by design, so to say, and I think your solution is the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might work better. It first collects all the registered pairs of schemes and authorities (and removes the duplicates), and then calls for the remaining unique pairs the unregisterLocations function.

```
public void unregisterProject(loc project, M3 model) {
    schemesAndAuthorities 
      = {<name.scheme, name.authority> | <name, src> <- model.declarations};

    for (<scheme, authority> <- schemesAndAuthorities) {
           unregisterLocations(scheme, authority);
    }
}
```

Will you give it a try? If it works, we can add it back to the standard library with some tests. The previous code was based on a different way of registering the locations, so the unregistration does not work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out.

Comment: I've run two tests with a handful of projects and the new method does seem to work better (if the old one was working at all). However, it's two tests and without exact memory usage it may be hard to determine the effectiveness.

Comment: thanks! true that's hard to see. in eclipse you can turn on "show heap status" in the preferences screen which should give some indication.

Comment: Yes, I was using the heap status to gauge the memory usage. I have been running my program and the unregister code works. I'm still seeing an increase in memory every processed project but I am not sure if it's due to registration issues. I'm sure that this could be ruled out by writing some unit tests! It would be great if this could be added to the standard library as the Registry class references the unregisterProject method in the comments. That was how I found out about this.